# jQuery selector : selecting ancestor whose descendent has attribute set to value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Struggling with CSS selector.  Want to select all FORM elements that are ancestors of {elements having class='required'}.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the nearest ancestor matching the selector, like this:

```
$(".required").closest("form")
```

or, alternatively you can use [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), like this:

```
$("form:has(.required)")
```

This translates to: `<form>` elements that contain an element with `class="required"`, same result (since forms can't be nested), just coming from the opposite direction.

Comment: Perfect.  I like the $(".required").closest("form") because in .Net I do run into nested forms (blasphemy I know).  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".required").parents("form").each(function(){
    $(this) ///... do something
});
```

something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

To select all ancestor form elements at any level would be:

$(".required form")

CSS:

.required form { }

Comment: I believe that your selector would give me all FORM elements who have an ancestor whose class = 'required'.  But I am looking for all FORM elements who have a descendent whose class = 'required'.  I just found the has() function so I think this may work : $("form").has("form .required")